# Proper Creation and Deletion of files - IOS

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager, disk, temporary-files

I am downloading multiple images and videos from a server to phone disk in order to achieve seamless playback (streaming is not an option). For images I simply turn the data into a `UIImage`. For videos I create a file in the `NSTemporaryDirectory` with the video data. Then associate a `AVPlayerItem` with that file.

```
 NSString *filePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"tempFile%i.mov",i]];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                    //Do background work
                    [fileManager createFileAtPath:filePath contents:videoData attributes:nil];
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        //Update UI
                        NSURL *outputURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];

                        AVAsset *asset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:outputURL];
                        AVPlayerItem *item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc]initWithAsset:asset];

                        NSMutableDictionary *dic = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:item, @"item", filePath, @"path", nil];
                        [self.pageImages replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:dic];
                    });
                });
```

At the end of each video, I delete that file.

```
NSDictionary *dic = [self.pageImages objectAtIndex:self.pageIndex];
if (dic) {
    NSString *path = [dic valueForKey:@"path"];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:path error:&error];
    }
}
```

I also loop through the `NSTemporaryDirectory` when the view disappears
 just to make sure all files have been deleted.

```
NSArray* tmpDirectory = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:NSTemporaryDirectory() error:NULL];
for (NSString *file in tmpDirectory) {
    NSLog(@"CALLED TO DELETE");
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), file] error:NULL];
}
```

When I first download my app, it only takes about 5.0mb of space. But after I watch a sequence of videos and photos it shoots up to >180.0mb. Why would this be even after I delete all the files I've created?

Comment: How are you measuring space taken? If you're in the simulator you can actually watch the tmp directory. Also I note that you're ignoring (passing NULL) as the error for the delete calls. Possible something is actually wrong?

Comment: @BenZotto I've printed the tempDirectory array before the delete and after. Before shows my files, after shows a nil array so the files are being deleted. And I am getting the space taken from My iPhone settings. Settings-General-Storage & ICloud-Manage Storage

Answer (score 0):

When you are downloading files temporary files are created. Maybe they occupy storage? You may obtain url to them in NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate method

```
-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
      downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask
didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location
```

Docs:

> A file URL for the temporary file. Because the file is temporary, you
>   must either open the file for reading or move it to a permanent
>   location in your app’s sandbox container directory before returning
>   from this delegate method.

Answer (score 0):

Calling removeItemAtPath does not delete the actual data in the file if there are still open file descriptors reading or writing that file. At the C level, the unlink() call will only actually delete the data if the file descriptor being closed is the last one that is open for that process. Also, be aware that the implementation of h.264 decoding under iOS can open and hold resources that were not directly opened in that specific process. Just be very careful with hardware resources via calls that go down to CoreVideo and the internal implementation of CoreVideo can share resources across processes under the covers.